# Paralleling LVPECL outputs?

Tags: digital-logic, transmission-line, high-frequency, high-speed

I have a pretty unusual application here, where I need to drive a fast differential signal fanning out into 8+ 100ohm transmission lines. The unusual part is this: the transmission lines must be perfectly synchronized. The exact same signal must be driven on all the lines. This rules out the usual PECL fanouts, since there is some skew on the outputs.

My plan is to take a PECL fanout buffer and parallel the outputs (i.e. short all the +Q outputs together, short all the -Q outputs together), then drive all the transmission lines from a single physical point. That would give the strong drive with a single waveform.

I have done this routinely with CMOS drivers, but this is my first time doing it with PECL. Are there any issues with this approach? For example, do I need to put some resistance in series with the PECL emitters?

I am using this chip: [CDCLVP1216](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cdclvp1216.pdf)

Here's an idea of what I want to do:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYoEc8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: There is no such thing as "perfectly synchronized". You must figure out the actual amount of skew you can tolerate. Whether it is 1 ns, or 100 ps or 1 ps, figure out the actual number. Then you can start figuring out how to achieve it.

Comment: The skew has to be <1ps.

Comment: I think you will have trouble. There will be transmission line geometry variations that cause more than 1 ps skew by the time your signals get where they are going. And with 200 ps rise-time it will be a challenge even to verify whether you've met the spec or not.

Comment: I have already implemented a similar circuit with CMOS drivers, and achieved the skew spec. I have a 20GHz scope so I was able to do the measurements with some effort (it is a differential measurement so noisy triggering isn't too much of an issue). The remaining issue was the jitter, which is largely due to slow rise time as you say. That is what motivates my interest in switching to PECL.<br>
Oh, I see you edited. With my equipment measuring 1ps skew with 200ps rise time is very easy. I had to do the same measurement with a ~600ps rise time already.

Answer (score 1):

One issue is that the PECL output is an open-emitter BJT, and it is biased by the pull-down resistor on the output. Traditionally this is 50 ohms to Vcc-2 V. Or if it's not convenient to make a sinking supply at Vcc-2, then something like 180 ohms to ground with some other means of getting 50 ohms AC termination.

To make sure all your outputs are biased the same, you'd need to do something like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0ZRVh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Whether everything still stays synchronized with all those external components present is TBD.

Comment: Ah... Unfortunately I must constrain the problem further. It has to be DC-coupled. I added a schematic in the OP to show the desired setup.

Comment: @ColinMarcus, can you give more explanation why? and what kind of signal is this? It might help to come up with solutions. For example, could you use CML rather than PECL signalling?

Comment: I might be able to use CML but my impression was that it is harder to interface with a receiver (and I'm not clear on what advantages if any it might have). The signal is a trigger, which has a random period but is not faster than 10MHz. The device is basically a fanout buffer with zero drift between outputs (and ideally zero skew as well). This is also imposing the requirement for DC coupling, since AC coupling would allow the rate to influence the average DC level of the signal.

Comment: I'm actually pretty confident that my overall architecture will work. I guess at this point I'm mostly wondering if I can safely parallelize the ECL emitters or not. Is there any need to use ballast resistors here? I am starting to think the answer is yes.

Comment: Is this a one off, for like a particle physics experiment or something? Because then maybe the risk of the parallel PECL gates is acceptable (or at least worth trying). But if you go CML, I know you can parallel the outputs with DC coupling, because it's a current steering design. Or, why not skip logic gates and just use a medium-power RF transistor as a buffer?

Comment: But really this isn't a discussion site. I don't have a solid answer for you (aside from "try it and see"). To just kick ideas around, visit the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering).

Comment: 1 millivolt of Ground noise, and 1nanoSec slew rate, will cause 1pF of jitter. Can you ensure the deterministic trash between GNDA and GNDB is < 1milliVolt?

Comment: @analogsysyemsrf It's worse: the PECL driver is Vcc referenced, not ground.

Comment: On the other hand he may be actually using the signal differentially.

Comment: I am using it differentially, and the GND bounce is synchronous, so it doesn't affect the jitter.